# Who does "his" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, who-whom

> You're trapped in a stalled elevator with your annoying boss. A fairy
> only you can see tells you to superglue his mouth. Otherwise, It'll be
> 18 hours before you're rescued.

Is *superglue his mouth* referring to the boss or the fairy?

Please note this statement is being narrated to you, this isn't something you are reading.

Comment: This appears to be part of a puzzle. It is very likely that we could tell by reading the whole thing.  Please give a link to the text or at least explain the rest of the story.

Comment: Well it is part of a game called "Split the room" where you basically fill in the blank to make both choices are hard as possible the answer given was "Superglue his mouth" so a debate happened because its a loophole to get out of the situation to superglue the fairy's mouth because of how it was worded

Comment: There is no loophole. If the fairy said, "Glue his mouth" then it must be referring to the boss. If the fairy said, "Glue my mouth" then it was referring to itself. If ***you*** were trapped in the lift, then you are the one who knows what the fairy said because you were there and you are the one telling the story.  Therefore you can tell everyone what it said and you can tell them what happened. This is a stupid game and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica You wouldn't say "glue my mouth" in reported speech, since "my" would then refer to the narrator. You would only say it if you were quoting the fairy.

Comment: @Barmar - Who else would you quote? The fairy is the only one we're told spoke.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I believe that Barmar is saying that you would only say it if you were *quoting* (as opposed to indirectly reporting the speech of) the fairy.

Comment: @Tanner Swett - That's not my point. The narrator says "a fairy tells you". It is talking to ***you***.  If the fairy tells ***you*** then you must know what the fairy said. Therefore you can tell the narrator what the fairy said - ***because you were there***.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Why assume that you must know what the fairy said? The narrator wrote only that you can _see_ the fairy, not that you can _hear_ it. ;)

Comment: Given that fairies are involved, any abuse of the (actually spoken) wording is his own fault.

Answer (score 25):

It is ambiguous, but we would probably assume that the word "his" is referring to the boss, for a number of reasons:

- Only you can see the fairy - they are a supernatural entity and it is unclear that you can touch them.
- Fairies are typically conceived as female (although they don't have to be).  The stereotypical boss is probably still imagined as male (although they by no means have to be).
- Your boss is annoying, so there is some logic to shutting him up.
- It is counterintuitive that the fairy would ask you to glue their own lips together.  As it is an unpleasant thing thing to do to someone, it is intuitively more likely that the fairy would ask you to do it to someone else.
- There is a sense that you are being asked to do something risky or transgressive, something that might get you into trouble but which carries the promise of a reward.  This makes no sense if you are talking about doing something to a fairy that only you can see.

Of course, if someone were asking you this, it could be a trick question (possibly one designed to illustrate gender biases - although as I've said, gender isn't the only reason for interpreting the sentence this way).

Comment: Is it worth remarking that the 'fairy' might be a personification of the person's own thoughts? We often say, e.g. 'a little demon whispered in my ear that I should glue the boss's mouth shut', when we do not mean to say that we believe in demons, or that we heard anything. You see a little demon (with pointed ears and whiskers) perching on Tom's shoulder sometimes in 'Tom and Jerry' cartoons. Also we might 'hear' suggestions from an 'imp of mischief'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The personification is irrelevant, because if you interpret it like that, the mouth of that personified fairy is similarly materialized, so it remains ambiguous whose mouth it is referring to. The personification argument doesn't really add to the posed question, as the same grammatical ambiguity would remain if it were talking about a third human being in that elevator.

Comment: What I don't understand is how supergluing anyone's mouth will affect how long it takes to be rescued.

Comment: As a gender-bias question, this would be better as:  *"You're trapped in a stalled elevator with your boss and your secretary. A fairy only you can see tells you to superglue his mouth. [for whatever nefarious reason]"* - who is "his" referring to?   (clearly unclear, but *gender-bias* would indicate the boss)

Comment: @Flater Having personified thoughts which involve harm to other (actual) people is a common trope. Having personified thoughts which involve harm to your personified thoughts is not a common trope.

Comment: I would probably have put those points in a different order, if not just have removed the first two. The fact that it makes much more sense to glue your boss's mouth rather than the mouth of the fairy removes the ambiguity without needing to consider gender or whether or not anyone else can see the fairy at all.

Comment: @Barmar I assume this is one of those hypothetical ethics questions, not meant to be taken as something that could actually happen or makes any real sense.  Though to play devil's advocate, it's possible that there's a limited air supply in the elevator, and the boss is using it up by annoyingly talking too much, so gluing his mouth shut might not make the rescue any faster, but it theoretically could prevent you both from suffocating...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Or maybe they meant that it will *seem* like 18 hours if you can't get the boss to shut up.

Comment: @Barmar I think there's a bit of a colloquialism going on there. I don't think the idea was that gluing the mouth shut would change the length of time, I think it was just a poorly phrased way of something something more like "Otherwise, this is going to be a very long 18 hours".

Answer (score 8):

This is known as an "[unclear antecedent](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_pronoun_unclear.html)", and is formally considered a grammatical error *even when the meaning is obvious*.  I recall an SAT study question from long ago, *"Neither the Christians nor the lions knew their hour was up"*.  The correct answer was to mark the sentence as an error.  It didn't even matter if the hour ended for both of them at the same time, it seemed.

The bright side: everyone does it - or at least, I do, much more often than I'd like to admit.

Comment: Can you please expand on why the sentence is ambiguous?

Comment: @WoJ because we don't know whether "his" refers to the boss or the fairy....................

Comment: @user253751: no, I meant in *Neither the Christians nor the lions knew their hour was up"*

Comment: "They" could be one or the other (or both).  But I should say, the study book's claim the sentence was incorrect was surprising enough to me at the time that it I remembered it decades later.

Comment: @WoJ in context, it might be clear that only one of their hours is up

Comment: The 'knowing' and the hour being 'up' are distinct. We know that the both the Christians and the lions do not know, but it is  ambiguous as to whether one or both of the lions and Christians are going to die.

Comment: @WoJ, The statement applies to both Christians and lions. It's not unclear; it's a trick question. "Nor" is an additive conjunction like "and", and not the exclusory conjunction "or" that it sounds similar to. It's bad grammar to mix "either-or" and "neither-nor" phrases for this reason (that and "neither-nor" always has negative connotations while "either-or" is neutral). The real question was, "Do pronoun grammar rules take precedence over conjunction grammar rules?" Yes, they do. The sentence is fine in conversational English, but it's not technically correct (the best kind of correct).

Comment: It's formally considered *by whom* to be a grammatical error?

Comment: Unclear antecedents are described as a problem by Dr. Wheeler's English 101 class at CNU, which I linked above.  I've been perplexed - on StackExchange, many things that I cite with hyperlinks have been regarded as altogether unsourced.  You're not the first.  But why???  I've never seen this before.  I'm considering abandoning their format in case there is something wrong with their scripts, and forcing the display of all hyperlinks as plain text, but I don't know if that would help.

Comment: The hyperlink appears in a different colour here and is clearly a hyperlink (in Chrome browser). Perhaps next time move it after what it a source for and put (source: hyperlink_goes_here_)? That should satisfy the curious..

Answer (score 6):

I think "his" refers to the boss. The reason is mostly explained by rjpond but I have another reason:

If the storyteller intended to say that the word "his" refers to the fairy itself, they would've said, "A fairy only you can see tells you to superglue his **own** mouth". Here, the word own is used to indicate that his refers to the same person as the subject.

Comment: I don't think *own* works well here - I'd generally expect it to refer to something belonging to the person *performing* the action, rather than the one instructing.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Citation for "own" relating to the person who's doing the action? None of my usual dictionaries have that usage, they just mention that it relates a specifies thing that belongs to someone as opposed to any thing of that type.

Comment: @user3067860 Hm, I thought that was standard usage, but you're right that there's nothing in the dictionaries. It's just that telling someone "X *your* own Y" is much more prevalent than telling someone "X *my* own Y".

Comment: @user3067860 To think about it, my only citation is Wiktionary. "Belonging to; possessed; proper to. Often marks a possessive determiner as reflexive, referring back to the subject of the clause or sentence", the best thing I can find with a more reliable dictionary is "used with a possessive to emphasize that someone or something belongs or relates to the person or thing mentioned." according to the Oxford Dictionary

Comment: https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/reflexive-pronouns also states that own is used to replace reflexive possessive pronoun.

Comment: But it is not reflexive, the fairy is telling the speaker to do it.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski "I don't want to stay in this hotel, take me back to my own house."

Comment: @mdewey it is reflexive, though. The part of your sentence after the comma seems to having nothing to do with the first half. That is irrelevant to whether the pronoun is reflexive or not.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this source](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_pronoun_unclear.html), the antecedent is whichever valid possibility is closest to the pronoun.  Since *his* in the example sentence could refer to the fairy, and *fairy* is closer than *boss*, the antecedent must be *fairy*.  Of course, if the sentence had read *A princess only you can see tells you to superglue his mouth*, then the antecedent would have to be *boss*, because a princess can't be a *he*.

Comment: I gotta say, typically pronoun resolution is informed by discourse salience much more than constituent order.

Comment: What is a valid antecedent?:) It's all a guessing game based on contextual and cultural knowledge. What if the first person referred to was David, the second Taylor Swift, and the pronoun "his"? You might assume it refers back to David, but what if Taylor is a male Taylor who just happens to share a name with the pop singer?  What if someone called Sarah-Louise is mentioned - but turns out to have changed their gender identity without yet changing their name? What if Jean is mentioned, but turns out to be a French Jean (m.) and not a British Jean (f.)? Someone called Nicola (ital.m./UK.f.)?